# Linux, can I specify port for outgoing udp packet?

Tags: linux, sockets, udp, port

In one linux process there are several opened udp sockets for sending, each with no bind(). Is there any way to specify port for outgoing packet? Or raw sockets are the only way to do so?

Clarifying one moment: I have to have several separate sockets, so bind() is not an options.

Thanks,
Alex.

Answer (score 2):

Just call `bind().` That's what it's for.

Comment: Problem is that I have to have several separate sockets, so I wish I could do so.

Comment: So? Just bind the sockets to all the various local ports they need to be bound to, and send from the one bound to the port you want to send from. And why do you think you need multiple UDP sockets?

Comment: I need to specify different CON_MARK per socket, that's why I need multiple. That's the reason why I can't resend it from one binded socket.